# Overlapping text in pantheon-terminal (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: command-line, fonts, visual-artifacts, pantheon

I've recently installed pantheon-terminal on my new Ubuntu 18.04 and I have a problem with overlapping text.

I've tried to change font with dconf-editor, but nothing has changed.

Does anyone can help me how to change spacing or solve it somehow?
Regards!

[image: Overlapping]

Comment: From where did you get pantheon-terminal? It doesn't seem to be in the regular repos of 18.04. Was anything else installed along with this terminal like another desktop environment?

Comment: I added elementary-daily repo and installed pantheon-terminal. Just like any other program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with installing Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting `pantheon-terminal` settings may help.

You can try the following command:

```
gsettings reset-recursively io.elementary.terminal.settings
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the system font type Monospace to "Monospace Regular". By default it was "Roboto Mono 10". This can be done in elementary tweaks or as indicated in this [link](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-change-the-default-terminal-font)

Comment: Intersting answer.  To improve it, you could summarize the key point of the link you refer to, thereby ensuring your answer reamins valid even if the link disappears.